# "wait window nowait" in .NET

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-foxpro

Is there something similar to "wait window  nowait" in Windows Forms (.NET VS2008) ?

This is a commonly used sentence in Visual FoxPro for debugging purposes and "quick and dirty" thermometers.

Comment: For those of us who don't use Visual FoxPro (most of us, I think you'll find), what does this statement actually do?

Comment: wait window is just an automatic popup window, no title / border that displays a simple message to the user and continues work with whatever it was about to do.  Much like a status of many tasks that may take a while, you can indicate to users "I'm still working on..."

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.  You could easily create a Windows Form and pop it up, or repaint a section on your own form to duplicate this functionality easily though.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could use [`Debug.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z9k5ydz.aspx) to write out debug information. The output will show up in the Output tab in the Visual Studio debugger when debugging your application.